# How to Poco C++ static libraries on Mac

Tags: poco

I have downloaded Poco from Git. I have followed their build instructions.
It generates dylibs by default. I cannot find **any** examples of how to build static libraries

I have tried:

```
./configure --static

cmake -H/path/to/poco -B/path/to/build

cmake --build /path/to/build
```

No matter what, it builds dylibs (.configure has no effect)

What is the "secret sauce" to build STATIC libraries?

Please provide a full example if you can.  The poco documentation "hints" at ways to do this, but among their many ways to build, they do not layout a formula for building static libs.  They only provide isolated hints flags - but not with what to use them, or in what sequence.  This is as real pain in the neck.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question. I found this works:

FIRST, you have to set $PROJECT_BASE and $POCO_BASE to the poco folder (where git cloned into).  Then....

./configure --static

make

The missing pieces - implied in the docs, but not made clear -  is that ./configure ONLY works if you are using the GNU/UNIX 'make' option (rather than cmake with cmake-build).  You also MUST have $PROJECT_BASE and $POCO_BASE "set" before you kick off the build.